# How do I make a makefile with a source folder?

Tags: makefile

I want to make a modular makefile with a PATH parameter but I can't figure out how.

This is what I had before:

```
CC=
CFLAGS=-c -stack-protect
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=
SSOURCES=
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
SOBJECTS=$(SSOURCES:.s=.o)
DEBUGFLAGS=-g -DDEBUG
EXECUTABLE=

all: CC += -DNDEBUG
all: $(SOURCES) $(SSOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) $(SOBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(SOBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

.s.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

debug: CFLAGS += $(DEBUGFLAGS)
debug: $(SOURCES) $(SSOURCES) $(LDFLAGS) $(EXECUTABLE)
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(SOBJECTS) -o $(EXECUTABLE)

clean:
        rm -rf *o $(OBJECTS) $(SOBJECTS)
```

And this is what I'm trying to do more or less:

```
PATH=
CC=
CFLAGS=-c -stack-protect
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=./src1 ./src1
SSOURCES=./src1 ./src2
FSOURCES=$(SOURCES:./=$(PATH))
FSSOURCES=$(SSOURCES:./=$(PATH))
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
SOBJECTS=$(SSOURCES:.s=.o)
DEBUGFLAGS=-g -DDEBUG
EXECUTABLE=

all: CC += -DNDEBUG
all: $(FSOURCES) $(FSSOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) $(SOBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(SOBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

.s.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

debug: CFLAGS += $(DEBUGFLAGS)
debug: $(FSOURCES) $(FSSOURCES) $(LDFLAGS) $(EXECUTABLE)
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(SOBJECTS) -o $(EXECUTABLE)

clean:
        rm -rf *o $(OBJECTS) $(SOBJECTS)
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Some inline comments and a sample error or description of what doesn't work would be helpful.  I do notice that the [substitution references][http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs] seem to replace `.cpp` with `.o` yet your rule works on `.cpp.o` (same for `.s`).

Comment: What version of Make are you using? (If you're not sure, try `make -v`.)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the files that the files you want to make .so are in the folder src2 and the files that you want to build and create and executable are in the in the folder src1.

```
VPATH = src1:src2:objects:include:libs

CFLAGS= -I ./include -Wall -g -stack-protect

LDFLAGS = -lstdc++
# You can append more libs as required.

CC = gcc


target: $(patsubst ./src1/%.c,./objects/%.o,$(wildcard ./src1/*.c)) ./libs/libmylib.so  
    $(CC) $(patsubst ./src/%.c,./obj_dbg/%.o,$(wildcard ./src/*.c)) $(LDFLAGS) -L ./libs -lmylib -o target

./objects/%.o: ./src/%.c ./include/*.h 
    @mkdir -p ./objects
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

./libs/libmylib.so: ./src2/%.c ./include/*.h 
    @mkdir -p ./libs
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

For makefile tutorial, you can check the following link.
http://www.tune2wizard.com/linux-makefiles/

Comment: Basically, you need to understand vpath, patsubst in case you want it very generic makefile.

Comment: clean should be PHONY.